# Xmonad vertical resizable tiles hides panel xfce

Tags: xmonad, xfce

I'm trying to have vertically resizable windows using xmonads and xfce. The problem is that once I change my configuration file to effect this using Xmonad.Layout.ResizableTile the windows cover my panel. How can I fix this?

Here is my xmonad.hs:

```
import XMonad
import XMonad.Config.Xfce
import XMonad.Layout.ResizableTile
import qualified Data.Map as M

myLayout = tall ||| Mirror tall ||| Full 
    where
    tall = ResizableTall 1 (3/100) (1/2) []

myKeys conf@(XConfig {XMonad.modMask = modm}) = M.fromList
    [ ((modm, xK_a), sendMessage MirrorShrink),
      ((modm, xK_z), sendMessage MirrorExpand)
    ]
newKeys x = myKeys x `M.union` keys xfceConfig x

main = xmonad $ xfceConfig
            { layoutHook = myLayout, 
              keys = newKeys
            }
```

Can someone at least explain why this configuration hides the panel? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**
I answered too quick, it seems below answer isn't sufficient. I haven't got XFCE installed to test, but [here](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Config-Xfce.html) and [here](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Config-Desktop.html) is more information about using XMonad and XFCE.

Sorry for not giving the definite answer...

---

Using `avoidStruts` should do the trick.

```
import XMonad.Hooks.ManageDocks
...
myLayout = avoidStruts (tall ||| Mirror tall ||| Full)
    where tall = ResizableTall 1 (3/100) (1/2) []
```

If this should only be applied to certain layouts, use it like

```
    myLayout = (myTall ||| myFull)
    where myTall = avoidStruts $ ResizableTall 1 (3/100) (1/2) []
          myFull = Full
```

Comment: Thanks, the second link was very helpful.